# About gitlab visibility level configuration

Tags: gitlab

I manage Gitlab on the server for internal users.
I want to grant some internal users the permission master/owner but on the other hand I want to forbid changing the visibility to public.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't seem possible with the current GitLab.
The [only restriction](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/public_access/public_access.md#restricting-the-use-of-public-or-internal-projects) currently in place is:

2014:

### Restricting the use of public or internal projects

> In [`gitlab.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/dbd88d453b8e6c78a423fa7e692004b1db6ea069/config/gitlab.yml.example#L64) you can disable public projects or public and internal projects for the entire GitLab installation to prevent people making code public by accident.

But if your users are admins, they would still be able to make a project public.

2016, as mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40126632/6309) by [Gregor Schmidt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817202/gregor-schmidt), the setting is [now in `Admin / Application Setting`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/public_access/public_access.md#restricting-the-use-of-public-or-internal-projects)  since [GitLab 8.3.0 (Nov. 2015)](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/52bcfd037fdc17bd73a674c248045dc750cc55c6).
See [`app/helpers/application_settings_helper.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/helpers/application_settings_helper.rb#L48-L50) and [`app/controllers/admin/application_settings_controller.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/controllers/admin/application_settings_controller.rb#L43).

The setting looks like this:

[image: Restrict visibility]

Comment: Thanks, it's just the answes I want to find.

Answer (score 2):

This setting was moved from a configuration file to the web ui. You may find it in the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/public_access/public_access.md#restricting-the-use-of-public-or-internal-projects).

> In the Admin area under **Settings** (`/admin/application_settings`), you can restrict the use of visibility levels for users when they create a project or a snippet. This is useful to prevent people exposing their repositories to public by accident. The restricted visibility settings do not apply to admin users.

Comment: Thank you for the update (+1) I have updated my answer accordingly (and found the setting in my own GitLab that I manage)